# How to change the background-color when scrolling down and repeat the process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code for changing the background-color when the user scrolls down the page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Phb4B/

The background color changes for the first two div's.How do I call the function to run again so that on the third div background color changes to beginning color?

```
    function call(){
        $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop(); 
        if(scroll_pos >= animation_begin_pos && scroll_pos <= animation_end_pos ) { 
            var percentScrolled = scroll_pos / ( animation_end_pos - animation_begin_pos );
            var newRed = beginning_color.red() + ( ( ending_color.red() - beginning_color.red() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newGreen = beginning_color.green() + ( ( ending_color.green() - beginning_color.green() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newBlue = beginning_color.blue() + ( ( ending_color.blue() - beginning_color.blue() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newColor = new $.Color( newRed, newGreen, newBlue );
            //console.log( newColor.red(), newColor.green(), newColor.blue() );
            $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: newColor }, 0);
        } else if ( scroll_pos > animation_end_pos ) {
             $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: ending_color }, 0);
        } else if ( scroll_pos < animation_begin_pos ) {
             $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: beginning_color }, 0);

        } else { }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this :[http://jsfiddle.net/Khursheed_Ali/Phb4B/26](http://jsfiddle.net/Khursheed_Ali/Phb4B/26/)/

Code :

```
function call(){
     var offset=0;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop(); 
    if(scroll_pos >= animation_begin_pos && scroll_pos <= animation_end_pos ) { 
       // console.log( 'scrolling and animating' );
        //we want to calculate the relevant transitional rgb value
        var percentScrolled = (scroll_pos-offset) / ( animation_end_pos - animation_begin_pos );
        var newRed = beginning_color.red() + ( ( ending_color.red() - beginning_color.red() ) * percentScrolled );
        var newGreen = beginning_color.green() + ( ( ending_color.green() - beginning_color.green() ) * percentScrolled );
        var newBlue = beginning_color.blue() + ( ( ending_color.blue() - beginning_color.blue() ) * percentScrolled );
        var newColor = new $.Color( newRed, newGreen, newBlue );
        //console.log( newColor.red(), newColor.green(), newColor.blue() );
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: newColor }, 0);
    } else if ( scroll_pos > animation_end_pos ) {
         $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: ending_color }, 0);
    } else if ( scroll_pos < animation_begin_pos ) {
         $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: beginning_color }, 0);

    } else { }
     // added   
    if(scroll_pos > animation_end_pos){
        offset+=blocks *2;
        animation_begin_pos=animation_end_pos; animation_end_pos+=blocks *2;
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: beginning_color }, 0);


    }

     if(scroll_pos<offset){
        console.log("offset:"+offset)
        offset-=blocks *2;
        animation_end_pos-=blocks *2; animation_begin_pos-=blocks *2; 
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you might want. [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/shree33/Phb4B/29/)

I have just changed one line.

```
    var animation_end_pos = blocks + blocks;
```

to

```
    var animation_end_pos = blocks * $('.block').length;
```

Animation should end at last block and not the second block, so I calculated total height (sum on heights all blocks. and here the assumption is height of all block would be same.)

```
    var blocks = $(".block").height();
    ...
    var animation_end_pos = blocks * $('.block').length;
```

And for better effect, I have set the background color of body to beginning color when the page loads.

```
    $("body").css("background-color", beginning_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed one line.

```
var animation_end_pos = blocks + blocks;
```

to

```
var animation_end_pos = blocks * $('.block').length;
```

Animation should end at last block and not the second block, so I calculated total height (sum on heights all blocks. and here the assumption is height of all block would be same.)

```
var blocks = $(".block").height();
...
var animation_end_pos = blocks * $('.block').
```